# custom meta box image field. Not getting image

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, meta-boxes

I am using a plugin for custom meta box. Image is uploaded through the dashboard of the admin panel. Now i want to show this image and my required place. I have tried different methods and functions but it is not working. It gets the id of the image but not he image.

**Code for custom meta box image field to register**

```
 add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );
 function your_prefix_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
 $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title'      => __( 'Image Gallery', 'textdomain' ),
    'post_types' => 'events',
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Image Upload', 'your-prefix' ),
            'id'   => $prefix . 'test_image',
            'type' => 'image_advanced',
             ),

        ),
    );
 return $meta_boxes;
}
```

**method 1 for getting image**

```
  $post_meta_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix.'test_image', true);
  var_dump($post_meta_data);
    if (!empty($post_meta_data[0])) {
        $custom_image =  wp_get_attachment_image($post_meta_data[0], 'thumbnail');
        var_dump($custom_image);
    }
    echo $custom_image
```

it shows the id of the image.

**method 2**

```
            $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $prefix.'test_image', true);
            var_dump($images);

            if ( $images ) {
                var_dump($images);
                 foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $img_full_url ) {

                    $full = wp_get_attachment_link($attachment_id, 'full');

                        echo "<li>";
                        echo $full;
                        echo "</li>";

                }
            }
```

it gives the error that invalid argument to for each loop.

Comment: What is the value you are getting for $prefix? Which plugin you used to create custom meta-box?

Comment: I am using Meta Box  Version 4.8.3 | By Rilwis.

Comment: I have searched in the database image is store at position 265. I have var_dump in both functions in both cases it shows string '265' (length=3).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code and confirm whether the code works or not?:

**Display Single Image**

```
$attachment_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_image', true);
echo wp_get_attachment_image(attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
```

**Display Multiple Image**

```
$attachment_ids = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_image');
foreach($attachment_ids AS $attachment_id){
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
}
```

Comment: $image =  wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'test_image',1));                                                                                               echo $image;

Comment: this code works for just one image. I have six to seven images what should i do for that

Comment: @waqasjr.developer: Please find the updated answer and let me know whether it works for multiple images or not?

Comment: Please concat the $prefix with id to make it work like charm :)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it out. Hope it saves your time.